# Binary Search Tree Output

Tags: c++

I am having trouble outputting a binary search tree.  I have to build the tree, and then place all the doubles from the tree in order into a vector, and then output that vector in order.  The problem I am having is getting it into the vector and outputting it.  When I just output the tree, everything works as it is supposed to.  The vector is supposed to get sorted and the std::vector* sort() is supposed to return a pointer to a vector.  The problem I am having is that I get a segmentation fault, and I don't know why.  Any advice would be appreciated.  Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>

struct ordered_set {
private:
    class node {
    public:
        double val;
        node* left;
        node* right;

        node(double v, node* l, node* r): val(v), left(l), right(r) { }
    };

    node* root;
    int size;

public:
    ordered_set();
    void insert(double x);
    std::vector<double>* sort();
    std::vector<double>* order(node*);
};

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "ordered_set.hpp"

ordered_set::ordered_set()
{
    root = 0;
    size = 0;
}

void ordered_set::insert(double x)
{
    node* data = new node(x, 0, 0);
    node* parent;
    parent = 0;

    if(root == 0)
        root = data;
    else
    {
        node* curr = root;
        while (curr)
        {
            parent = curr;
            if(data->val > curr->val)
                curr = curr->right;
            else
                curr = curr->left;
        }
        if(data->val < parent->val)
            parent->left = data;
        else
            parent->right = data;
    }
    ++size;
}

std::vector<double>* ordered_set::sort()
{
    node* ndptr = root;
    return order(ndptr);
}

std::vector<double>* ordered_set::order(node* top)
{
    node* curr = top;
    std::vector<double>* set;
    std::vector<double>::iterator it = set->begin();

    if(curr != 0)
    {
        order(curr->left);
        set->insert(it, curr->val);
        ++it;
        order(curr->right);
    }
    else return set;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems here.

First, you never define the vector that `set` is pointing to.

For instance:

```
std::vector<double>* set;
std::vector<double>::iterator it = set->begin();
```

Set is a **pointer** to a `std::vector<double>`.  When you first declare it, it's just a memory value on the stack with some undefined value and it's pointing to some undefined place.  Therefore when you dereference it on the next line, BOOM, you get a segmentation fault since you're accessing memory outside the allowed memory the OS has allotted to your process.

Secondly, unless you *must* use a pointer to a `std::vector` for you homework assignment, pass around a reference to the vector in `order()`, and return a copy of the vector from `sort()` ... it will make your life a lot easier as well as avoid memory leaks from the user of your code who many not call `delete` on the pointer you return to them from `sort()`.

Third, you've defined `order()` as a recursive function ... so you can't define your vector in each iteration of the function and place a value in it, otherwise you're going to be creating a new vector for every function call.  So you need to define your vector in the actual `sort()` method, and then pass the vector as a reference to your `order()` method like the following:

```
std::vector<double> ordered_set::sort()
{
    node* ndptr = root;
    std::vector<double> set;
    order(ndptr, set);

    return set;
}
```

Lastly, you will need to re-define `order()` so that does an in-order recursive traversal of your tree (compared to a pre-order or post-order traversal).  This means that it will recursively go to the left-most child first and end with the right-most child of the tree, processing each node in-order:

```
void ordered_set::order(node* top, std::vector<double>& set)
{
    node* curr = top;

    if(curr == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    //go to the left-most child
    order(curr->left, set);

    //at this point we've now processed all children to the 
    //left of this node ... so we can now process this node itself
    set.push_back(curr->val);

    //now process all children to the right of this node
    order(curr->right, set);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation.  After you said it, it made perfect sense and I said, "No duh!"  Thank you so much!